# removePersistentDomainForName not working for NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm writing an OS X app. I'm trying to clear NSUserDefaults.

I'm currently doing:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```

But it's not working, i.e. all the key-value pairs are still there when I print the user defaults.

I've also tried adding:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

still no luck.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `removePersistentDomainForName:` does not work *on OS X 10.8*. Furthermore, these things are not functional also:

```c
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:@{} forName:[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:@{}];
```

To work around the problem, you may set an arbitrary key-value pair to the domain then remove the pair:

```c
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:@{@"": @""} forName:[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier]); // => (null)
```